# Excluding Values from a CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to determine how to exclude values from an array based on a CSV file.  This is the best option I have so far:

```
$arrIgnore = import-csv "ignore.csv"

foreach($objIgnore in $arrIgnore){
    $objAll = $objAll | where {$_.Name -ne $objIgnore.Name}
}
```

This doesn't filter out a single item from the array.  If I write out the problem with the values in strings:

```
$objAll = $objAll | where {$_.Name -ne "value1"}
$objAll = $objAll | where {$_.Name -ne "value2"}
```

It works correctly.  I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake but I can't figure it out.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does $objIgnore.Name exist?  Check the output of $objIgnore.Name and make sure it contains what you think it does.  I think $objIgnore.Name might be empty.  If not, you still might have to cast it to a string from a PSObject.  What does this output?

```
foreach($objIgnore in $arrIgnore){
    $objIgnore.Name
}
```

I was able to get the following code to work as you desired.

```
$arrIgnore = import-csv ".\ignore.csv"
$objAll = import-csv ".\all.csv"

foreach($objIgnore in $arrIgnore){
     $objAll = $objAll | where {$_.Name -ne $objIgnore.Name}
}
```

where ignore.csv contains

```
Name  
srv1  
srv2  
srv3  
srv4  
srv5
```

and all.csv contains

```
Name 
srv1 
srv2 
srv3 
srv4 
srv6 
srv5 
srv7 
srv8 
srv9 
srv10
```

At completion, $objAll returns

```
Name 
---- 
srv6 
srv7 
srv8 
srv9 
srv10
```

Comment: I think I needed to cast it to a string because the following is what worked:  
    foreach($objIgnore in $arrIgnore){
        $objAll = $objAll | where {$_.Name -ne ($objIgnore.Name)}
    }

Answer (score 1):

FYI, an easier way to do this is to use the -notcontains operator with your array of strings that you want to ignore.

For example:

```
$array = @('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5')
$array | Where-Object {@('value2','value3') -notcontains $_}
```

This passes through your array containing all objects once instead of one time for each value you want to exclude.

Comment: How does this work if both of the arrays I'm going through are objects that have properties and aren't just strings?

Comment: @Scott:  Why are you using a CSV if you only have one property?

Comment: @JasonMArcher In this exact script the CSV actually has two properties, the name of a VM and the host it should reside on.  I'm trying to filter out the VMs that have an assigned host.